# Cassandra stress-tool failing

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-stress, cassandra-stress-tool

I'm trying to test cassandra-stress tool. By starting the tool with a write I get this error:

```
/bin $ ./cassandra-stress write -node 10.xxx.xx.1:31xx5
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 10.xxx.xx.1:31xx5: invalid IPv6 address
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.StressSettings.getJavaDriverClient(StressSettings.java:200)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.SettingsSchema.createKeySpacesNative(SettingsSchema.java:79)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.SettingsSchema.createKeySpaces(SettingsSchema.java:69)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.StressSettings.maybeCreateKeyspaces(StressSettings.java:207)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction.run(StressAction.java:55)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Stress.main(Stress.java:117)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 10.xxx.xx.1:31xx5: invalid IPv6 address
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.addContactPoint(Cluster.java:849)
    at      org.apache.cassandra.stress.util.JavaDriverClient.connect(JavaDriverClient.java:116)
    at     org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.StressSettings.getJavaDriverClient(StressSettings.java:191)
    ... 5 more
```

Configuration details:

```
Version: 3.0.8
native_transport_port: 31xx5
start_native_transport: true
listen_address: "10.xxx.xx.1"
```

When I check the port, it's using tcp6 protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the below and it worked.

```
./cassandra-stress write -node "IPv6 equivalent of IP" -port native=31xx5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the port with he `-port` flag instead:

```
$ ./cassandra-stress write -node 10.xxx.xx.1 -port 31xx5
```